# Dynamic initialization of child classes in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'd like to dynamically initialize the child classes of a base class. Here's what I've tried so far. Is there a better way / more correct way?

```
class FileFromUrlBase(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self._parse_url()
        self.f = self._get_file()

    def _parse_url(self):
        pass

    def _get_file(self):
        pass

class FileFromUrl1(FileFromUrlBase):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(FileFromUrl1, self).__init__(url)

    def _parse_url(self):
        self.param_from_url1 = ...
        self.param_from_url2 = ...

    def _get_file(self):
        # Getting the file from Url1...

class FileFromUrl2(FileFromUrlBase):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(FileFromUrl2, self).__init__(url)

    def _parse_url(self):
        self.param_from_url3 = ...
        self.param_from_url4 = ...

    def _get_file(self):
        # Getting the file from Url2...
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? At first glance, it appears you are neglecting to call `super()._parse_url` from each subclass's inherited method.

Comment: @chepner, each subclass has a different way of parsing the URL and different attributes.

Comment: Instead of `pass` in those methods in the parent, I would recommend raising `NotImplementedError` instead.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is call the super __init__ function, why do you define the __init__ function for the children?  Any non-explicitly defined function will be inherited from the parent class.